# Why is arsenic trichloride more likely to be polar than aluminum trichloride?

Tags: lewis-structure, polarity

According to my chemistry teacher, $\ce{AsCl3}$ is more likely to be polar than $\ce{AlCl3}$. Why is this? As I understand it, the difference in electronegativity is what makes a compound more or less likely to be polar, and $\ce{AlCl3}$ has a much greater difference between the two elements' electronegativities. So why isn't it more likely to be polar of the two?

Comment: By the way, welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) using LaTeX syntax. If you receive useful answers, consider [accepting](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because $\ce{AlCl3}$ has a [trigonal planar geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_chloride) (leading to no permanent dipole moment) and $\ce{AsCl3}$ has a [pyramidal geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arsenic_trichloride) (leading to a permanent dipole moment).

Comment: Why do their geometries differ? Both are, according to VSEPR, AB3 - type molecules without any lone pairs (unless my lewis structures and Google's are way off), so why is AsCl3's pyramidal?

Comment: Arsenic centers will look like nitrogen centers, which *do* have a lone pair.